# Opening div onClick as pop up with content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

My issue is all my divs open at the same time when one is clicked. Rather I    want only one div to zoom and grow as popup with its content that is clicked.

**Controller:**

```
var app = angular.module('angulo', []);
app.controller('testController', function ($scope, $location, $rootScope, $log) {

    $scope.CustAppre = [        
    {appre:"Project Appreciation",by:"Ziva Roe",custContent:"1 You are doing a very good job"},
    {appre:"Agile Work Process",by:"Joe Roe",custContent:"2 You are doing a very good job"},
    {appre:"Customer Speaks",by:"Michael Charles",custContent:"3 You are doing a very good job"},
    {appre:"Work Appreciation",by:"Gwen Charles",custContent:"4 You are doing a very good job"},
    {appre:"Leadership Appreciation",by:"Joe Roe",custContent:"5 You are doing a very good job"},
    {appre:"Agile Appreciation",by:"Sherlee James",custContent:"6 You are doing a very good job"},        
    ];

    $scope.hiddenElements = [];
    $scope.IsElemVisible = function(elemId) {
        return $scope.hiddenElements[elemId];
    }
    $scope.openBigDiv = function (elemId) {
        $scope.hiddenElements[elemId] = true;
    }

});
```

**HTML:**

```
  <div ng-controller="testController">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 checkContent" ng-repeat = "appreciate in CustAppre">
                <div class="quote-inner-wrapper">   
                    <div class="arrow_box blue-texture-bg" ng-click = "openBigDiv(appreciate)">
                        <blockquote class="no-bg white quotation-white">
                            <p>{{appreciate.appre}}</p>
                            <div ng-show="IsElemVisible(appreciate)">{{appreciate.custContent}}</div>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                    <a role="button" class="customerName blue" href="#">{{appreciate.by}}</a>        
                </div>
    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src = "test.js"></script>
```

Please advise. [Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f98engoa/4/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making your own life complicated by trying to use another array to store the opened "appre" (what does that mean? Why don't you use real English names?).

You're also trying to use objects as indices in an array, which is not possible.

Here's all you need:

```
$scope.openBigDiv = function(appre) {
    appre.opened = true;
};
```

and in the view:

```
<div ng-show="appreciate.opened">{{appreciate.custContent}}</div>
```